# Como executar um select no pentaho

Tags: pentaho, job, transform

Gostaria de saber como eu executo comandos sql no pentaho, preciso fazer a busca de certos dados dando select porém já utilizei table input e sql query e não funcionou.

Answer (score 3):

**1 - Inserir um STEP Table Input**

Conforme exemplo abaixo:

[image: Table Input]

**2 - Editar o STEP Table Input**

Nesse passo precisamos configurar o banco (é importante também testar a conectividade). A configuração do banco está fora do escopo da pergunta, entretanto ela é bem intuitiva. Eventualmente pode ser necessário instalar um driver para conexão.

O campo SQL deve conter a consulta que tu montou.

[image: Editando table input]

Em seguida clique em PREVIEW. Se o Pentaho te retornar uma lista, a configuração é válida e o Input Step foi construído de forma efetiva.

Exemplo de PREVIEW:

[image: Exemplo PREVIEW]

**3 - Table Output**
Para efetivamente realizar alguma interação com os dados, você deve adicionar steps subsequentes, que manipulem os dados ou gerem alguma saída (fora do escopo da pergunta). Sugiro um Table Output ou um File Output (apenas para ilustrar).

[Fonte](http://kettlebeginners.blogspot.com/2011/08/table-input.html)